# Dismiss Keyboard for textview

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, dismiss

I have been trying to get the keyboard during a textview to dismiss but it STILL doesn't change the return button's action.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText     text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n"
    {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

I was following the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsnoS8_G2SU

By now i have essentially copied the code 100%.

P.S. the textfield's outlet is named Textviews

Please help!

EDIT: Someone marked this as duplicate so let me explain why it isnt - I already have done what it tells me to do, and I'm not sure why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: So you are using `UITextfield` but implement `UITextview` delegate? Try to change it to `UITextfield` delegate.

Comment: Alternatively (if you are indeed using a `UITextView`), make sure you've included `textView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad(...)`, and that you're view controller is conforming to `UITextViewDelegate` (`... ViewController : UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate`).

Comment: Most importantly: are you using an `UITextField` or an `UITextView`? (You mix these terms in your question above, and the solution for the two differ).

Comment: To clear it up, I am using a UITextView. I also have UITextFields, and I have already hooked them up in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made everything correct, but there is one step missing.

In order to hide or show the keyboard via the responder you have to set the delegate otherwise it won't work.

You can do it for example in the viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    myTextView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: _If_ the OP is actually using an `UITextField` rather than `UITextView`, then he has not done everything correct. _If_ he, on the other hand (as we assume?) is using the latter, then `myTextfield` is an unfortunate property name in your example above. Also, `overide` should be `override`, and `viewDidLoad` should include `super.viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score -4):

If your textfield is Textviews then you should have

Textviews.resignFirstResponder()

I hope this helps

Comment: didn't you look on his question?